# Comment package not working (with a case)

Tags: comments

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{comment}

\title{title}

\author
{
\begin{comment}
...
\end{comment}
    Author
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Verbatim-like environments (among which there is `comment`) cannot go in the argument to another command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{comment}

\title{title}

\begin{comment}
A comment
\end{comment}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}

    \maketitle

    \tableofcontents

    \section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

It's because an environment can't be in an argument (yes even the `comment` argument).

Comment: Thanks. Apparently you are right and I should have known this. I shouldn't have expected that the `comment` package could work as the same way as /* */ in C/C++ which is at the compiler level rather than relying on and at an external 3rd party library level.